# How to Push to Heroku From Personal Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I've recently set up bare, shared repository on a personal server and would like to push to heroku directly from there -- that is, NOT use github.

I guess I'm not sure I understand every part of the line where we add a remote:

```
git remote add heroku myherokuusername?@heroku.com:myherokureponame?.git
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:taraswebapp.git # normally this
git remote add heroku tara.byte@heroku.com:taraswebapp.git
```

Other information:
I'm working on mac os x, and have recently installed the relevant heroku toolbelt.
my origin is: tara@192.168.1.160:/rails_projects/taraswebapp.git, where that is the static ip of my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing the changes locally, you were once able to `git push heroku master` from your repo.  This second bare repo on your server would be another thing completely different.

Now if you are sharing your bare repo, that'll be a different story.

### Update #1:

Store your app in git from heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#store-your-app-in-git) should get you started and show you how it's done with another repo too.

Comment: so i should be able to push to heroku from my local machine? can you elaborate any more on how?